Should there be close confirmation popup on top of another popup?
I have a popup which automatically shows up after a page. This popup is a utility which asks the users if they wish to pre populate a new form by copying responses from one of their previous forms. Steps are:

It shows a list of forms submitted in past, the user clicks on a line item and clicks 'Proceed'
Same modal transitions into a state with detailed description of the form the user has selected, and then user clicks on proceed to get it done.

In both the states, there are 2 buttons, Primary is 'Proceed' or 'Confirm' and secondary is Cancel and X on top right.
Clicking on 'Cancel' or 'X' will close the modal but never show it for this form instance again. I'm worried - what if the user clicks on 'X' accidentally, is it right to show a 'Close' confirmation popup on top of it?

You should provide users with an alternative way to access the "copy from" functionality in case they close the popup. If you're concerned about "accidental clicks" due to user confusion (rather than layout issues), you can first prompt the user with a straightforward selection ("Start blank" / "Copy from existing").
Also, consider whether this functionality is so common that users should be prompted with it every time they create a new form. If this is a repetitive process, a popup could become annoying.

It sounds like you're trying to solve the wrong issue. From what you've describe above I see the user not being able to re-access the form as the issue instead of users clicking X on a modal.
My suggestion is if your users need to pre populate a new form then have the control and freedom to do so when they need (usability heuristic #3).
I know I've seen close confirmation windows in some apps. I don't think it's ideal UX as it's not very standard.
